# Problems with providers when building with angular-cli@latest

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am building a project with `angular-cli` and, after upgrading to the version `1.0.0-rc.2`, I am currently having an issue to `ng build` the app. When I try to do so, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 46:16 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/Rkok/Documents/Projects/capitola-vr-frontend/src/app/app.module.ts
```

The error is located in `app.module.ts` and it is connected to the `useFactory` property inside the provider `APP_INITIALIZER`. This is the complete code:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        // Modules list
    ],
    declarations: [
        // Declarations list
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: 'Window', useValue: Window },
        PostsService,
        UserService,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER, 
            useFactory: (users: UserService) => () => users.onResize(), // The error is in this line
            deps: [UserService],
            multi: true
        },
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: (posts: PostsService) => () => posts.loadData(), // And in this other one
            deps: [PostsService],
            multi: true
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Do you know what is the best way to solve this issue? Thanks in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even we have faced this issue but if we declare using normal "function" syntax it works instead of using ES6 "=>" syntax.

Updated code would look something like:

```
function users(users: UserService) {
   users.onResize()
}

function posts(posts: PostsService) {
  posts.loadData()
}

@NgModule({
imports: [
    // Modules list
],
declarations: [
    // Declarations list
],
providers: [
    { provide: 'Window', useValue: Window },
    PostsService,
    UserService,
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER, 
        useFactory: users,
        deps: [UserService],
        multi: true
    },
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: posts,
        deps: [PostsService],
        multi: true
    }
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

It should work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks man, but the error still persists. Apparently I have to store the function inside a service or a variable, a pass the value in that way

Comment: You could try to declare your useFactory functions with a function name above @NgModule decorator in the same file and reference them in useFactory using function names

Comment: I have trie to use a global variable or export the constant, but it throws again the error. How would you declare it?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried the same and I get this error `Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Reference to a non-exported function`

Comment: Hey man! I have edited the answer. Now it works :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved by exporting the function from the app module like this :

```
export function users(users: UserService) {
   users.onResize()
}
```